# PHPUnit: Failed opening required `PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php`

Tags: php, phpunit

I installed `PHPUnit` with:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Trying to run a simple test, but getting:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php'
```

How do I install `PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase`?

The test is simply:

```
class TestFunctions extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function test_str() {
        $this->assertEquals('foo', 'bar');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story package:

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story
```

Or manually from [github repository](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-story/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Story/TestCase.php).

Comment: I was able to install PHPUnit_Story, but still getting: `Failed opening required 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php'`. Where did pear install it?

Comment: `/usr/share/pear` however the contents of `PHPUnit` is simply `Framework/MockObject`. Do I have to manually `require()` PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you need to reinstall whole PHPUnit package through `pear`. Because it will correctly install all dependencies: `sudo pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit`.

Comment: per the PHPUnit website, pear installer support for PHPUnit is going away by end 2014.  Already there are warning messages produced using that method to install.  Justin is using the new approved method for installing it, and probably wants the 'new for the *.phar case install' instructions.  I know I do! :)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately none of the suggested fixes worked for me. The typical response is to install the phpunit/PHPUnit_Story module. While that will put you in the right direction, it did not solve my problem.

I registered an autoload function in my boostrap.php file. This most likely replaced the autoload function, registered by PHPUnit, used to autoload PHPUnit's classes. I commented my autoload function implementation and the issue went away.

**EDIT**

In response to @user3265472; It's been a while since I've worked on this, but I want to say that the "fix" was to set the include paths at the beginning of the bootstrap.php file and then manually loading the classes as you would normally:

```
/**
 * Configure include paths used by the unit tests.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function configure_include_paths()
{
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__) . "/mylib");
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__) . "/mylib2");
    set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/lib");
}

configure_include_paths();
```

This allowed me to do something like the following at the beginning of every file:

```
require_once("MyClass.php");
```

instead of having to determine where the class was in relation to the current class file.

I also want to say that no matter what I did I couldn't get class auto-loading to work as I would have liked. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I've registered an autoload in my bootstrap too. I think I'm having the same problem. If I were to comment it out, I wouldn't be able to load my application classes though. How did you get around this?

Comment: Hi. I had the same problem. I fixed it by using `@include_once` instead of `require_once` in my autoload function.

Answer (score 1):

Like Bakyt Abdrasulov mentioned, this seems an autoloader issue.

See his comment:
"I fixed it by using @include_once instead of require_once in my autoload function."

Answer (score 1):

If you install phpunit with composer these errors will not come

step 1:
Create a composer.json file in your project root:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.4",
        "phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.3",
        "phpunit/phpunit-story": "*",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"": "src"}
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin/"
    }
}
```

step 2:
Install composer into your project using:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Ensure composer is executable:

```
chmod +x composer.phar
```

Let composer install the dependencies:

```
./composer.phar install --dev
```

Check you have a project specific phpunit version installed:

```
bin/phpunit --version
```

the above specified  is a softlink

```
ls -la bin/phpunit
bin/phpunit -> ../vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

Afterwords you can make softlink of  'phpunit' from vendor directory into directory of php in use. 
This will remove all warnings related to

```
PHP Warning:  include(classes/PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php)
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'classes/PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php' 
PHP Warning:  include(classes/Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader.php)
```